# Dynamically cast object to a type, when type is unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, linq, casting, expression

I have a method for fetching data from database, and it is generic:

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetData<T>(IQueryable<T> data, some more parameters)
```

data is unfiltered collection of db entities, and GetData does filtering, sorting, skipping, taking upon that collection...

When I provide variable of type IQueryable (T being, for example, Document) as first parameter, as I usually do, it, of course, works:

```
IQueryable<Document> data = ... 
GetData<Document>(data, ....);
```

Now, I have a need to "calculate" the first parameter dynamically. For that I use LINQ Expressions which will evaluate into IQueryable, but I dont know which T at compile time. I was thinking something like this:

```
Expression db = Expression.Constant(new DataModelContainer());
Expression table = Expression.Property(db, tbl); /* tbl = "Documents", this is the whole point */ 
Type type = table.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Expression call = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "AsQueryable", new Type[] { type }, table);            
object o = Expression.Lambda(call, null).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

At this point o INDEED IS IQueryable (IQueryable), and as such should be able to serve as an argument to GetData. But, I have only 'object' reference to it, and naturally, cannot use it like that.

So, my question is: Is there any way to dynamically cast 'o' to 'IQueryable' when o is exactly that. I know that cast is compile time thing, but I am hoping someone has a workaround of some sort. Or maybe I am trying too much.

Comment: Have you tried making o `dyanamic`, as in `dynamic o = Expressin.Lambda...`?

Comment: I did not, but I did just now. And I think it will do the trick just fine. Opens up so much possibilities. It occurred to me, but always backed out thinking its too much work. Thanks, man!

Comment: Wait, I'll post that as answer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `dynamic` feature. Dynamic is great for situations where you already have to do reflection:

```
dynamic o = Expressin.Lambda(...
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a load of this fellah:

First. We presume the class surrounding your **GetData < T >** method is called **Foo**:

```
public static class Foo {

    public static IQueryable<T> GetData<T>(IQueryable<T> data, int bar, bool bravo) {
        // ... whatever
    }
```

Then we try to reflect upon the MethodInfo of **GetData < >** (and by that I mean the actual template, generic definition, not a closed particularization of it). We try to obtain that (and succeed) at the birth of the **Foo** class.

```
    private static readonly MethodInfo genericDefinitionOf_getData;

    static Foo() {
        Type prototypeQueryable = typeof(IQueryable<int>); 
        // this could be any IQuerable< something >
        // just had to choose one

        MethodInfo getData_ForInts = typeof(Foo).GetMethod(
            name: "GetData", 
            bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: Type.DefaultBinder,
            types: new [] { prototypeQueryable, typeof(int), typeof(bool) },
            modifiers: null
        );
        // now we have the GetData<int>(IQueryable<int> data, int bar, bool bravo)
        // reffered by the reflection object getData_ForInts

        MethodInfo definition = getData_ForInts.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        // now we have the generic (non-invokable) GetData<>(IQueryable<> data, int bar, bool bravo)
        // reffered by the reflection object definition

        Foo.genericDefinitionOf_getData = definition;
        // and we store it for future use
    }
```

Then we write a non-generic variant of the method which should call the specific generic method with regard to the actual element type being sent as a parameter:

```
    public static IQueryable GetDataEx(IQueryable data, int bar, bool bravo) {
        if (null == data)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        // we can't honor null data parameters

        Type typeof_data = data.GetType(); // get the type (a class) of the data object
        Type[] interfaces = typeof.GetInterfaces(); // list it's interfaces

        var ifaceQuery = interfaces.Where(iface => 
            iface.IsGenericType && 
            (iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>))
        ); // filter the list down to just those IQueryable<T1>, IQueryable<T2>, etc interfaces
        Type foundIface = ifaceQuery.SingleOrDefault();
        // hope there is at least one, and only one

        if (null == foundIface) // if we find more it's obviously not the time and place to make assumptions
            throw new ArgumentException("The argument is ambiguous. It either implements 0 or more (distinct) IQueryable<T> particularizations.");

        Type elementType = foundIface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        // we take the typeof(T) out of the typeof(IQueryable<T>)

        MethodInfo getData_particularizedFor_ElementType = Foo.genericDefinitionOf_getData.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
        // and ask the TypeSystem to make us (or find us) the specific particularization
        // of the **GetData < T >** method

        try {
          object result = getData_particularizedFor_ElementType.Invoke(
              obj: null,
              parameters: new object[] { data, bar, bravo }
          );
          // then we invoke it (via reflection)

          // and obliviously "as-cast" the result to IQueryable
          // (it's surely going to be ok, even if it's null)
          return result as IQueryable;

        } catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
          // in case of any mis-haps we make pretend we weren't here
          // doing any of this
          throw ex.InnerException;

          // rethink-edit: Actually by rethrowing this in this manner
          // you are overwriting the ex.InnerException's original StackTrace
          // so, you would have to choose what you want: in most cases it's best not to rethrow
          // especially when you want to change that which is being thrown
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Some good stuff! MakeGenericMethod crossed my mind too. Thanks for being so detailed and patient. But, i might have trouble even sending IQueryable to the method, I only get object as a result to stand in place IQueryable<T>.

Comment: If think you can of course do this IQueryable query = obj as IQueryable and then use the method GetData (non-nongeneric). What you were not able to do was to say IQueryable<SRKBSUT> q = obj as IQueryable<SRKBSUT> (where the acronym stands for SomeRuntimeKnownButSyntacticallyUnknownType :))

Comment: Oh. oh my mistake.Now I get it ! Anyway.. Since .NET 4.0 you know we have the ability to cast IEnumerable<Horse> to IEnumerable<Mammal> (covariance) and IComparator<Mammal> to IComparator<Horse> (contravariance). So in short, at least you could cast (explicitly) the resulting object to IQueryable<object> (since object is compatible with anything and IQueryable is covariant with itself).After that it's up to you I guess to do what you want to do, generically speaking with the resulting query(query some more,or stop and bring the results and maybe use dynamic, or maybe a dispatcher to N methods)

Comment: If dispatching to specific logic result set processors with if statements is to little and dynamic is to much (to dangerous) might I suggest Impromptu-Interface ?:http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/ It is something like (although it's not clear I have these 4 methods, I know I have them (always), and although dynamic is great, it's too much, I don't want an infinite, unbounded spectrum of methods,I want these 4,then Impromptu-Interface is the right thing.It was created before dynamic.With dynamic you could make yourself wrappers of your own and forget Impromptu(which reflection.emits